# MVC5 Identity/OWIN - Signout events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

How to detect all possible SignOuts? Is there a way to get some event when SignOut is made manually, by timeout and any other possible ways?

I need to know when user authentication ends like i know that it starts when SingIn is called.

I'm using both internal accounts and external (like Facebook).

Comment: Manual signout? Yes. Some timeout function when they are on your site? Sure. All signouts? Not possible because of the inherent disconnected nature of the web. Why don't you explain why you need to do this because there's likely a better way.

Comment: @Shoe I want to make special init page for new users. This is a game. When user registers, after first login i want to redirect user to special page, where he will create character. I don't want to allow user that is already authenticated and validated to be able to go to other pages until he creates char. So i figured out that ill add flag to database "isInitialized", set only when user already done char creation. But i don't want to SELECT database at each request to check if user already "isInitialized". I wanted to load "isInitialized" at SignIn to "cache", and clear it at SignOut.

Comment: This point should also be the initialization of all database default values for new player. After first login, when I'm already sure that email is validated i can populate database for new user.

Comment: You can use a session variable to store it.

Comment: @Shoe it seems i will need to :(. I just wanted to do it without session. There are always problems. What if session will time out before authentication will time out and i'm loading data at SignIn? What if session start is made without authentication and i'm loading data at Session_start. I will need to SignOut always at session start or try to load data at 2-3 different places.

Answer (score 0):

I need a spot that i can initialize user session when user is already authenticated. Below is code that should do the job, i don't like it at all. I need to check session at each request to be sure that flag in session is already loaded and was loaded for current user.

In future that flag will be probably a whole class of properties from DB.

Can't believe that there is no better way of detecting when user is SignedIn/Out.

What i've done is:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeSession_Authenticated();
}

protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeSession_Authenticated();
}

private void InitializeSession_Authenticated()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
        return;
    if (!System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return;

    string userName = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_VAR.USER_ISINITIALIZED] == null || 
        HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_VAR.USER_NAMEFORSESSION] != userName)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_VAR.USER_NAMEFORSESSION] = userName;
        HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_VAR.USER_ISINITIALIZED] = GetFlagFromDB(userName);
    }
}
```

EDIT: @Shoe thanks :P...